# Run postgresql functions in python and gets error

Tags: python, postgresql, distance

I would like to run below postgresql function queries in python but I keep getting error message says

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT 
ST_Distance_sphere(st_makepoint(32.836956,39.925018)
,st_makepoint(28.990174,41.036857))")
df = cursor.fetchall()
df

InFailedSqlTransaction: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

How can I fix this? Thank you.

Comment: I've seen this error several times although always through an IDE (pgAdmin being one) but not Python. Typically I've found this results from a previous transaction which has not been committed nor rolled back. Don't know if this is your issue, but it might be worth looking into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [psycopg docs](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/faq.html), you probably have an error in your command (SQL).

> There was a problem in the previous command to the database, which
>   resulted in an error. The database will not recover automatically from
>   this condition: you must run a rollback() before sending new commands
>   to the session (if this seems too harsh, remember that PostgreSQL
>   supports nested transactions using the SAVEPOINT command).

I highly recommend using `try/except/finally` clause in your database connections. Or use `with` statement.

Here is an example from http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-python/transaction/:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(dsn)

# transaction 1
with conn:
    with conn.cursor() as cur:
        cur.execute(sql)

# transaction 2
with conn:
    with conn.cursor() as cur:
        cur.execute(sql)
conn.close()
```