# Java with PostGIS "ERROR: function st_makepoint(double precision, double precision) does not exist" but query works on SQL

Tags: java, jpa, postgis

I am trying to make a query through my JPA repository but I'm getting the following error:

`ERROR: function st_makepoint(double precision, double precision) does not exist Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. Position: 83`

**CompanyRepository**

```
@Query(value = "SELECT c.* FROM company c JOIN store s ON c.store_id = s.id " +
            "WHERE ST_Within(ST_MakePoint(s.longitude, s.latitude), :polygon)",
            nativeQuery = true)
    List<CompanyEntity> findStoresInPolygon(@Param("polygon") Geometry polygon);
```

**If I try to make the same query on SQL it works as expected.**
(I have a list of stores saved and only a couple of them fall within that polygon shown below, and those are the ones being retrieved)

```
SELECT c.*
FROM mySchema.company c
JOIN mySchema.store s ON c.store_id = s.id
WHERE ST_Within(
    ST_MakePoint(s.longitude , s.latitude),
    'POLYGON((10.7522 59.9139, 5.3221 60.3913, 10.3951 63.4305, 5.7331 58.969, 10.7522 59.9139))'
);
```

Thanks in advance!

**OTHER POSSIBLE REVELANT INFO:**

Not sure if it's relevant but latitude and longitude are being stored like shown below:

**StoreEntity**

```
@Column(nullable = false)
private Double latitude;

@Column(nullable = false)
private Double longitude;
```

The schema is defined in the `application.properties` and other queries work, I'm only having a problem with the ST_MakePoint.

I've read a bunch of other topics not only here in stackoverflow, official PostGIS docs, but also on other websites as well and tried different alternatives, if anyone have any sugestion I appreciate it.

Some of the things tried and did not work include cast lat and long to double and numeric, put coordinates directly on the ST_MakePoint.

I am expecting for the results from Java to be the same as the ones from SQL query.

(the posts stakoverflow have as possible duplicates have differences and I've already tested for what was different)

Comment: maybe the user running the query doesn't have in its path the schema where postgis is installed

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I am getting: No function matches the given name and argument types when executing poytgis function with psycopg2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71736879/i-am-getting-no-function-matches-the-given-name-and-argument-types-when-executi)

Comment: If it works if you use makepoint with fixed coordinates in the string then you know it has something to do how it inserts the variables from s

Comment: @JGH I have the schema set with PostGIS and checked all the user configs.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe that link does not help, but thank you!

Comment: @TimothyDalton The MakePoint does not work with fixed coordinates, already tried it :(

Comment: Are you certain? If the error message is that the function (with the proper argument data types) cannot be found, either you connected to the wrong database or your `search_path` is wrong. And that is what the question I referred to is about. Did you try adding the schema name to the function call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding the `public` to my current schema in the `application.properties` file

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/myCustomdb?currentSchema=customname,public
```